# write a large RDS file to a sparklyr dataframe- databricks

Tags: r, apache-spark-sql, databricks, sparklyr, azure-databricks

I'm trying to convert an R dataframe loaded in databricks to a sparklyr dataframe but I think the `copy_to` function which is usually used cannot cope with the file size. The files I need to convert range from 780MB - 4.7GB.

The code is :

```
chloedf<-copy_to(sc,Chloe)
```

and error returned:

```
Error in writeBin(utfVal, con, endian = "big", useBytes = TRUE) : Error in writeBin(utfVal, con, endian = "big", useBytes = TRUE) : 
  attempting to add too many elements to raw vector
Error in writeBin(utfVal, con, endian = "big", useBytes = TRUE) : 
  attempting to add too many elements to raw vector
In addition: Warning message:
closing unused connection 11 (raw())
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `copy_to()` [wasn't intended for large datasets](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/615).

There are a couple of options here.

1. Instead of `rds` format, save the original R dataframe as a CSV.  Then you can read it directly into Spark using `spark_read_csv(sc, "/path/to/mycsv.csv")`.  This is the easiest method.
2. Try using `SparkR::createDataFrame()` instead.
3. Install Apache Arrow on your Databricks cluster and retry the `copy_to()` command.  [Here](https://github.com/marygracemoesta/R-User-Guide/blob/master/Spark_Distributed_R/arrow.md#what-is-apache-arrow) are some instructions for setting that up.